# How to create a structural component in angular2

Tags: angular

I created a structural directive that can add or remove the element on which it is applied.

Now, I will want that the directive add a content to the element on which it is applied. But it does not seem possible using a directive, as it has not its own template.
May be I should rather create a component instead of a directive. This official guide seems to imply this :
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

> Angular offers more sophisticated techniques for managing layout such as structural components that can take external content and incorporate that content within their own templates. Tab and tab pane controls are good examples.
>   We'll learn about structural components in a future chapter.

The chapter does not yet exist, so how to create a structural component ?

Here is the code using my directive :

```
<div class="..." *myDisplayer="form.controls.comment"></div>
```

The `myDisplayer` directive add or remove the div according the condition linked to the control. Now I will want that the directive add a `<img>` in the div when it is added.

Comment: Please add your code. I can't make any sense of this sentence "Now, I will want that the directive a content to the element on which it is applied."

Comment: I corrected my sentence because I had forgotten a word. You can see my directive like the ngIf directive, except that it does not take a boolean as a parameter but an AbstractControl that it observes to determine itself the condition. That's ok. Now I will want that the directive can add a content (an image) to the element it controls when it appears.

Comment: Add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. I still can't make any sense of your description.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR:

***Content Projection*** (oldy known as *Transclusion* in Angular 1) seems to achieve the behaviour of a *"Structural component"* with the use of `<ng-content> ... </ng-content>`.

- See the explanation of [Projections](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html) on Rangle's Angular 2
  Training Book.
- See more in [*toddmotto.com* about Transclusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content) in Angular 2 with
  `ng-content`.

---

Not sure if the term "**Structural component**" still applies or resolves to what I found as the answer.
Seems that **Projections** are the correct term for this *Structural component* term for this behaviour described at the bottom in the Structural directives guide.

Basically we can achieve this by using the `<ng-content>...</ng-content>` directive tags inside the component's template. This component will display or "project" the stuff inside the Component's element tags (and thus acting as a *structural component* if I'm correct applying the term here).

### Example:

This `<projection-example>` component will **project / transclude** what is passed into it:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'projection-example',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <p>End of {{name}}</p>
  `,
  styles: [`* { border: dashed red 1px; }`]
})
export class ProjectionExampleComponent {
  name: string = 'Projection Example component';
}
```

for example, when used in the App component (as the parent):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <projection-example>
    <p>My <i>projected</i> content.</p>
    </projection-example>
  `,
  styles: [`
    projection-example { display: block; border: dashed blue 1px; }
    p, i { border: dashed blue 1px; }
  `]
})
export class App {
  name: string = 'Angular2';
}
```

This results in (as for Angular 2.4.1):

[image: Plunker results]

- *See it here https://plnkr.co/edit/5r5vR1?p=preview*

---

Offtopic: I accidentally got over this as an example of this behavior in one guide (while searching on Google *"angular 2 advanced"*). Too bad this is still not in the official Angular 2 Guide (as when writing the answer).

In my opinion, the term *"Structural component"* is misused in the official Guide, doesn't exists, or Searching in Google does not give any relevant results but this question only.